# Superfish - Change the Space between each button

Tags: css, joomla, superfish

How do I change the space between each button of my superfish menu?
I am using the vertical Menu css.

Comment: Some source codes would be helpful and a live example too. use jsfiddle.net to create an example if you don't have it live, not everyone (I) knows what superfish is and it might also be a problem with either the CSS or Joomla or even markup, so if we can see what you're having trouble with we can help better. :)

Answer (score 1):

If what you're looking for is spacing out the items that are at the first level of your Superfish drop-down menu, just add some margin to the direct children of the container of the .sf-menu. Something like this should work :

```
ul.sf-menu > li {
margin-right:10px
}
```

Of course that wouldn't work on IE 6, so if you need to support IE 6 you could go with :

```
ul.sf-menu li {
margin-right:10px
}
```

and then cancelling out the margin for the children LIs :

```
ul.sf-menu li li {
margin-right:0
}
```

and so on depending on how deep your nested ULs are

Comment: What I wanted was the close up the gap. Do I insert a negative value?